# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when saving NSData to Realm

Tags: swift, realm, nsdata

I want to save an image from an imagePicker with Realm. It works when I choose an picture but not when I don't choose one. I tried to save a standard image when no image is chosen.
But I get the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Location:

```
class Location: Object{
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var locationDescription = ""
dynamic var latitude = 0.0
dynamic var longitude = 0.0
dynamic var created = NSDate ()
dynamic var category: Category!
dynamic var imageData: NSData!
}
```

Add New Entry Controller:

```
 //Image Picker
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var selectedImage = UIImage()


@IBAction func loadImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes =     UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
//MARK: - Delegates Image Picker
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    imageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func addNewLocation() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    //convert image to NSData
    let standardData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!)! as NSData
    let selctedImageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.9)!)
    let emptyData = NSData()
   // let data = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 0.9)!)
    var data = NSData()

    if selctedImageData == emptyData{
        data = standardData
    }
    else{
        data = selctedImageData
    }

    try! realm.write {
        let newLocation = Location()


        newLocation.name = self.nameTextField.text!
        newLocation.category = self.selectedCategory
        newLocation.locationDescription = self.descriptionTextField.text
        newLocation.latitude = self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.latitude
        newLocation.longitude = self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.longitude
        newLocation.imageData = data


        realm.add(newLocation)
        self.locations = newLocation
    }
}
```

Edit:
I replaced the Category Model with an string which is generated from an query.

```
class Location: Object{
...
dynamic var category = ""
dynamic var imageData: NSData!

}
```

Comment: In `addNewLocation()`, do something like `if let imageView.image` or something similar?

Comment: I already tried something like this. It has not worked for me. Do you have a bit more specific idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
class Location: Object{
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var locationDescription = ""
dynamic var latitude = 0.0
dynamic var longitude = 0.0
dynamic var category = ""
dynamic var imageData: NSData? = nil

}


 //Image Picker
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var selectedImage = UIImage()


@IBAction func loadImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
    //MARK: - Delegates Image Picker
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    imageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func addNewLocation() {


    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!)! as NSData






    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        let newLocation = Location()

        newLocation.name = self.nameTextField.text!
        newLocation.category = self.selectedCategory
        newLocation.locationDescription = self.descriptionTextField.text
        newLocation.latitude = self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.latitude
        newLocation.longitude = self.selectedAnnotation.coordinate.longitude



        newLocation.imageData = imageData

        realm.add(newLocation)
        self.locations = newLocation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Location` model has two properties that are implicitly unwrapped optionals (IUOs): `category` and `imageData`. IUOs in Swift are useful when you know that the value might have to store `nil`, but you can guarantee that it will never be accessed in that state, in ways that the compiler can't imply automatically.

In this case, you're accessing one of these properties before having set its value to something other than `nil`.

Perhaps `self.selectedCategory` is `nil` at the point where it's assigned to the `newLocation.category` property? It's hard to say given that you didn't include anything related to this value in your sample.

If you can't guarantee that those IUOs will ever be set to something non-nil upon access, I'd suggest that you define them as optionals instead, and handle their nil case specifically.

```
class Location: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var locationDescription = ""
  dynamic var latitude = 0.0
  dynamic var longitude = 0.0
  dynamic var created = NSDate()
  dynamic var category: Category?
  dynamic var imageData: NSData?
}
```

Comment: The category can't be nil. You always have to select one category. I tried to make imageData optional but can't find a way to make an optional NSData property.

Comment: The error message you posted would indicate otherwise.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. The Category must be selected otherwise there is a popup on the screen which says to fill all fields. But i don't want to force to choose an image, it should be optional.